# PDF page flip/turn software

Tags: pdf, flip

I'm slowly dying inside with this request but I've been asked to look into PDF page flip's. Does anyone have any suggestions? I've trawled the web but they don't seem to match what I need:

1. Be a piece of software rather than online to cut down on costs (ideally we'd be looking to spend around £250).
2. Allow embedding of video, swf's etc.
3. Ability to adjust the look of the viewer.
4. Look semi decent (there's some terrible one's out there).
5. Although not essential, it would be nice if it was iphone/ipad compatible.

If anyone has come across any page flip software then I'd really appreciate your input.

Comment: If the software point is only to cut down costs then converting each page to an image (you can do this in Photoshop with a batch) will allow you to use this http://codecanyon.net/item/flipbook-jquery-powered-w-media-gallery/152110 it only costs $6 and is pretty good with just images, you can embed flash and text etc.

Comment: Cool, how much coding would need to be done on that? Say I had a 10 page PDF that had links, video, buttons etc etc. Would it require me to first of all know jquery and secondly code it all in? The less work the better really!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've gone with Issuu, had to ditch some of the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://www.codebox.es/pdf-to-flash-page-flip before. Just upload a PDF and it will create a flash page flip. Looks like you may need more than it provides though, such as embedded videos.

Answer (score 1):

FlexPaper Zine has been released quite recently and looks good with HTML5 support for devices

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/flexpaper_flip_zine.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If the software point is only to cut down costs then converting each page to an image (you can do this in Photoshop with a batch) will allow you to use this http://codecanyon.net/item/flipbook-jquery-powered-w-media-gallery/152110 it only costs $6 and is pretty good with just images, you can embed flash and text etc.

You wouldn't need to know jQuery because the plugin does all that for you. You'd just need to convert each page to an image and do a simple HTML

```
<div class="flipbook">
<img src="image source"/> //Page 1
<img src="image source"/> //Page 2
<img src="image source"/> //Page 3
.. //Page n
</div>
```

You'd customise the options in jQuery at the bottom but they are REALLY simple and already set up to defaults for you (just change the values etc.)

Purchasing it through the site means you get support from the creators if you need a hand.

Comment: Although this is something I could do, there will be non tech people also using it and they'd never be able to handle any code. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You could use a form to allow non technical users to generate pages. Use PHP to build an administrative area where they can add pages and then you read from the database and generate the relevant HTML. All they would have is the need to upload an image or flash file or video. You could take care of generating the code with PHP - or any serverside technology for that matter

Comment: We didn't really want it to turn into a massive overhead, ideally some software (or online if it's cost effective!) with a nice GUI would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://page-flip.com/ before. It is quite user-friendly, allowing you to import a PDF and publish all the flash files. It should cover most of what you want.

Comment: That got ruled out due to price and the fact that it wasn't Mac compatible. Definitely along the right lines if it wasn't for those two factors.

Comment: ah. You didn't mention the Mac part :)
http://page-flip.com/products/photo-album/ is mac compatible but not sure how much it can do.